# Google fonts only showing one weight in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I'm trying to use a Google font on my website in different weights.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500" rel="stylesheet">
```

Everything works fine in Chrome and Safari.  But in IE, everything looks bold, no matter what font-weight I set an element to have.

I have found one work around.  If I load each font-weight individually (with the code below), everything works in IE.

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500" rel="stylesheet">
```

That works, but it's inefficient.  Anyone have a better solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What if you set `body{font-weight:300;}`? the default value is `normal` which is `400` but you didn't include it within your kit.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I already have that set.

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem in IE11. http://jsfiddle.net/5s5o5h9n/1/ looks the same in all browsers.

Comment: Perhaps the question is, what version of IE? What version of Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was that IE was set to load intranet sites in compatibility mode. Since the dev environment is on the local network (and thus an intranet site), IE was switching into compatibility mode without my knowledge. Turning that setting off fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the proper google fonts suggested line:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Or put the fonts into your css file:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,500);
```

Don't know what else could help, sorry.